# AES Salting iterations, How many required?

Tags: encryption, aes, salt

I am trying to execute a simple Encrypt and Decrypt AES and I was trying to use salting. These values will be stored in the DB and retrieved from there. (I cannot use hashing) I am using static key and static salt for the time being.

My question is how many iterations of salting should I do? I mean I have to store the value in the DB and I see that at 2 iterations (128bit key, 42bit salt) I get a encrypted string of 152 charaters for 40 characters. For 4 iterations, it's 364 characters for 40 characters, for 8 iterations 1536 characters for 40 characters and for 16 iterations, a ridiculous  19968 characters for 40 characters.

So what should be my optimal number of iterations?

```
 public static String AESencrypt(String value) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        String valueToEnc = null;
        String eValue = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            valueToEnc = salt + eValue;
            byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
            eValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
        }
        return eValue;
    }

    public static String AESdecrypt(String value) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        String dValue = null;
        String valueToDecrypt = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(valueToDecrypt);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            dValue = new String(decValue).substring(salt.length());
            valueToDecrypt = dValue;
        }
        return dValue;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you work with the raw `byte[]` instead of converting to base64 every iteration? The base64 step is likely the majority of your pain. It should be outside the loop.

Comment: Note that except for the given answer, you also make the mistake to use `getBytes()` without specifying a character encoding, using the Sun inner class `BASE64Encoder`, probably using `"AES"` which will result in ECB mode encryption, not specifying an IV. I cannot see what is in `generateKey()` but maybe that's for the best.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What, *exactly* do you think you are achieving? Please only implement *standard* algorithms in *standard* ways and don't make stuff up. It's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salting is used on passwords to derive keys. It is not used on ciphertext, not even if it is base 64 encoded. Salting is used to make it harder for an attacker to find the password using brute force or rainbow tables. It is typically used by a PBKDF such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

In your case it doesn't matter how much you encrypt; if the attacker tries the key, decrypts the ciphertext and then finds base 64, the attacker will know he has found the key, and can simply do the number of iterations again.

In general, it does not make sense to encrypt things multiple times; block ciphers themselves already should contain a sufficient number of "rounds".

Comment: so you mean that I can drop the base 64 encoding and the salting and should just use the o/p from the AES for storing?

Comment: You only need base64 to store the ciphertext as a string (of characters). AES does not require salting. That said, an as indicated, your implementation seems to be missing other essential functionality to be considered secure.

Comment: can you give me a link where I can understand such stuff?

Comment: Well, I just finished https://www.coursera.org/crypto to learn a bit more about the underlying theories. Personally I just read specifications and have a job that requires me to enjoy crypto and related technologies 6 hours a day :)

Comment: The right way to say "thank you" is an upvote and/or accept, chettyharish :)

Comment: BTW, you have a total of 9 questions that have been answers without any accept, and some of them certainly have been answered. Maybe it is a good idea to review some of the older questions. If the questions are not usable by anyone else (and have no usable answers) you could also delete them.

Comment: The problem is that most people are just adding to comments, so I cannot tick them as the correct answer